# Password strength validation with regex in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to make a regex for password strength in python however my problem is,

[BELOW MY SOURCE CODE]

```
import re

def PasswordValidator(password):

     passregex = re.compile(r'''[a-z]+
                                [A-Z]+
                                [0-9]+
                                 ''',re.VERBOSE)
     search = passregex.search(password)

    if search == None:
        print('not found')

    else:
        print(search)



text = input("Enter: ")

if len(text) < 8:
    print("Password too short")


else:
    PasswordValidator(text)
```

the regex wouldn't work because it has to match the lower case first which is the [a-z] but i want it to be able to match any of the character classes.So I don't know if i should make another regex for the uppercase i.e [A-Z] but my knowledge on regex is basic so I don't know how to go about that.

Comment: Use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` to match any of these characters.